# Switch between Create and Edit view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a viewcontroller which have the function of creating an object, let s say, a calendar event.

The thing is that I will have another viewController which will havbe the function of editing the calendar object.

They have the exactly same UI, same number of fields, labesl and ect, except the fact that nav bar is different (Edit button vs Create Button)

My usual way of dealing with such situation is that I use this one viewController as both edit and create viewController.

Then, before I call the viewController, I pass a state to tell the viewController if it is supposed to be in Edit or Create Mode.

The problem here is that, I find the viewController to be HUGE and there is too much logic in the viewController to distinguish the create and edit function.

Is tehre a better way in dealing with such situation?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see,

> Option 1 **Move your UI into a Single UIView**

```
 final class ParentView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet private weak var titleLabel:UILabel?
    var view: UIView! //<-- any object from your UI should be a subview to this view     
    var didPressButton:(()-> Void)? = nil 
      /*
         use delegates or closure just like didPressButtons, 
         to pass actions or input value from your any actions from the user 

        Important: think of reference cycle and stay away from them lol 
      */

      @IBAction private func didPressButton(sender:UIButton) {
          didPressButton?()
     }

     /*
         if you wish to set UI from data, you can do the following:  

     */
     public func setTitleLableWith(string:String) {
        titleLabel?.text = string 
     }

     deinit { 
         titleLabel = nil 
     }
   }
```

> Option 2 **Think of OOP**

Create your `BaseViewController` with all your UI and methods, then hide or `override` any methods you'd like from any `Derived` Class

The choice is yours, but I like the first option. :) Happy Hunting